# preg_match check for number and whitespaces

Tags: php

I'm working on a simple login & register system as practice and I want to check strings if they contain a number and at te same time with preg_match, but how can I make that happen?

```
if (preg_match('~[0-9]~', $name)) { echo "match";}
```

This is the code I have so far. It only can find a number inside a string, but how can I add that the preg_match also searches for whitespaces. I have tried multiple things but I just can't find a way to make it work. I hope someone can help me out.

If there is something unclear please let me know, and I will do my best to help you.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Did you bother doing a simple search for "regex whitespace"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find white spaces you have to use \s in the regular expression.

```
preg_match('~[0-9\s]~', $name)
```